# How to check authorisation without database overhead?

Tags: node.js, session, authorization

I am using node.js. I was thinking of just storing a session id in the session variable, so that every time I make a request for a route, the server checks in the database whether the user with that session id is authorised to access that page.

This seems a bit inefficient, since there will be a database call for every page request. I know I could just store some data in cookies / session variable for this purpose to avoid the database call, but then I am susceptible to tampering..

How do other web developers handle this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A server-side session and associated encrypted session cookie used with https is secure.  So, just keep a value in the server-side session that tells you whether that user has been authenticated or not and all you have to do is check that variable in the server-side session object.  This is how every web-site I know does things.

The NPM module `express-session` used with a suitable session store will implement most of this for you.

If you have a specific reason why you think this isn't secure, please share those reasons so they can be discussed.

Here's a general article about securing node.js servers and point #6 is about securing session cookies: [9 Security Tips to Keep Express from Getting Pwned](https://nodesource.com/blog/nine-security-tips-to-keep-express-from-getting-pwned/).

Comment: I guess what I was trying to store as little information in the session cookie as possible, simply so that if someone "reads" the information in the cookie, they do not learn anything about how the site functions internally. I guess a signed cookie and https should help avoid tampering.

Comment: @KaizerSozay - Something like express-session only stores a single session ID in the cookie (only long encrypted string).  All other user session state is stored server-side in the actual session object which nobody outside of the server itself has access to.